# "No ssl package found." warning on GAE production

Tags: google-app-engine

I know this question doesn't have much info, I'm hoping someone's seen something similar before.

I get the following warnings on my GAE PRODUCTION log:

```
W 2012-11-04 12:23:11.529 /base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/lib/cacerts/urlfetch_cacerts.txt missing; without this urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates

W 2012-11-04 12:23:11.529 No ssl package found. urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.
```

These seem to be issued from the python2.7 runtime rather than any of my code or the libraries I'm using.

I don't see these warnings on my local dev_appserver

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you importing google.appengine.api.urlfetch_stub anywhere? That's where the warning is coming from.

EDIT: To be clear, there's no issue here other than the log spam. This warning is intended for the dev_appserver.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd accept the answer if this was an answer.  Most likely it's because I have a symlink to the SDK's httplib2 inside my project.